# Compiler error and classes cannot be found

Tags: java, package

I am having an issue compiling my program.
Error message occurs is: 
"Error:(19, 24) java: package battleship.Board does not exist.

I have total 3 classes.
BattleshipMain, Board, Ship

They are all in the same src folder, but still compiler says that it cannot find Board and the Ship class.

Could someone explain? Should I have package folder under src where all these three .java files would be inside and I just declare package on every class and import class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, the app is looking for a package called "battleship", in which your `Board` class file should be. If the file is in the "src" folder, then your package structure needs to be corrected.

Based on the info in your post, your file structure should probably look something like this:

```
> src
    > battleship
        > Board.java
        > Ship.java
        > BattleshipMain.java
```

And each of those files should declare their package to be `battleship`.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.